# Unwanted space to right of text box in IE 9 standards mode and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

Can anyone please explain why and how to get rid of the space between the right of the input textbox and the red border

IE: http://jsfiddle.net/fQHGA/

```
<div style="float:left;border:1px solid red">
    <label style="float:left">asdasdfasdff</label>
    <input style="display:block;margin-left:100px">
</div>
```

IE, Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/cxDvF/2/

```
<div style="float:left;border:1px solid red">
    <div>
        <label style="float:left">asdasdfasdff</label>
        <input style="display:block;margin-left:100px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks fine to me (Chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/fQHGA/

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I have now added an example for Chrome. Sorry i did not have Chrome to test with before.

Answer (score 1):

I keep repeating myself.

http://www.ntutorials.com/css/understanding-floating Please read this tutorial.

Simply to answer your question, when you float an element, define its width. Otherwise it may cause problems across different browsers.

Furthermore, if you have your default style settings, inputs may have a little margin. That may be the reason, as well. Try to reset the margins.

**EDIT**

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with that example that you have provided in jsfiddle but here are some points.

1. input has no ending tag. Therefore, `</input>` is not valid.
2. you're trying to float a label and an input which both are inline elements, hence there is no need to float them.
3. If you don't know the width then you should find some work arounds. Floating without width is not browser-consistent.

Comment: Widths are unknown/auto and not maintained

Comment: Thanks Savas 

1.    Corrected 
3.    How about following example http://jsfiddle.net/eDNg6/

Comment: @user1083577 display:table is unnecessary there. You need to follow some tutorials. Check the website I suggested or go to w3school and look at html tutorials, that will be easier for you to learn :)

Comment: display:table is to shrink the unknown width, so i can horizontal center align